# dhclient: No broadcast interfaces found, but eth0 is up and broadcast

Tags: debian, dhcp, dhclient, eth0

I'm experiencing a common problem with dhclient. But I wasn't able to find a clear solution to this problem.

System:

- ReadyNas RN104
- Stock Debian for armhf
- Just upgraded to Debian Jessie
- Self-built monolithic (ie. no modules) Kernel 4.0.5

If I call `sudo dhclient eth0` manually everything works fine.

**How do I tell dhclient to automatically use eth0?**

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 72:84:91:48:ff:51  
      inet6 addr: fe80::7084:91ff:fe48:ff51/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:63 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:532 
      RX bytes:6743 (6.5 KiB)  TX bytes:26010 (25.4 KiB)
      Interrupt:26 

$ sudo dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
...
No broadcast interfaces found - exiting.

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# max address from uboot printenv ethaddr, eth1addr
pre-up ip link set dev eth0 address 28:XX:XX:XX:XX:X4
pre-up ip link set dev eth1 address 28:XX:XX:XX:XX:X5

$ dmesg |grep eth
mvneta d0070000.ethernet eth0: Using random mac address 72:84:91:48:XX:XX
mvneta d0074000.ethernet eth1: Using random mac address f2:0c:25:7d:XX:XX
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
mvneta d0070000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
mvneta d0070000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

$cat ./devices/platform/soc/soc:internal-regs/d0070000.ethernet/net/eth0/flags
0x1003
```

Comment: Tried pump instead of dhclient. More or less the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, I recently upgraded a Raspberry PI 1 Model B from Raspian Wheezy to Jessie. After boot, interface eth0 was up, but no DHCP address assigned. Running `dhclient` without arguments resulted in `No broadcast interfaces found - exiting` and running it as `dhclient eth0` worked correctly.

The solution for me was to add `auto eth0` to */etc/network/interfaces* (not sure why, though):

```
auto lo
auto eth0

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```